# Netbeans Edit PHP on VirtualBox Shares

Tags: php, netbeans, virtualbox

Setup:

Virtual Box on OSX running Ubuntu Server 17.

Opening a project on Netbeans on one of these shares is fine and the files editable, however as soon as I click on a different window on OSX (so losing focus from the Netbeans window) and return to Netbeans the file is instantly uneditable, however the share is still traversable on the OSX filesystem. Its as if it suddenly becomes read only (though unchange and still is rwxrwxrwx as shown on from an SSH window into the virtual box (!00% reliable).

Answer (score 0):

PHPStorm handles this situation perfectly.

The only caveat here is that if there are a few shares on the VBox its necessary to write a bash script to unmount/remount them in turn but its not that complex, otherwise PHPStorm does nothing when attempting to open local project.